# Transaction/Commit no Core Data, é possível?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data

Existe o conceito de Transaction e Commit no Core Data?

Possuo uma base no app que é alimentada por um arquivo externo, porém são muitos dados e a aplicação leva em torno de 2 minutos para realizar está importação então preciso rodar a mesma em background.

Existe alguma forma de iniciar uma Transaction quando eu começo realizar a importação (apagar todos os dados antigos e inserir os novos) e faça o commit quando terminar?

Como é possível usar o app enquanto a importação está sendo realizada, é possível que ocorra o acesso a algum dado que tenha sido deletado e isso crashe o app (por isso preciso realizar em uma transaction).

Uma alternativa que eu pensei é criar um cache dos dados em banco se não for possível fazer Transaction e Commit.

Comment: Chute: os métodos beginUndoGrouping e endUndoGrouping  não resolveriam seu problema? (o método undo serve para fazer o rollback de fato em caso de falha.) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733233/ios-core-data-how-to-implement-the-sql-transaction-function

Comment: Qual método vc usa pra copiar os dados, GET ou POST? se possível por o código.

Comment: @WilliamMonteiro no que o método usado importa? Meu problema é apenas com o Core Data, mas pelo que vi aqui basta salvar o contexto apenas depois de terminar a importação completa e não a cada insert/delete. Vou testar isso ainda e se resolver fecho a pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não existe esse tipo de pensamento no Core Data.

Quando se faz um fetch dos dados e os transforma em objetos, mesmo após fazer mudanças nesses objetos, não necessariamente você está salvando eles.
Só é feita a inserção/edição de dados, caso chamado o método de save do core data. Isso ocorre porque todos esses objetos só estão na memória do aplicativo e só são retornados para a base utilizando o método `-save` do core data.